# Integral of Laplace-Beltrami operator over a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, compactness, laplacian

Consider an equation 
$$\Delta u=-he^{u}$$
over a compact 2-manifold $M$, where $u\in C^{\infty}(M)$.

In paper "Curvature functions for Compact 2-Manifolds" by Kazdan&Warner it is said that integration of the above equation over the manifold $M$ leads to the identity:

$$\int_{M}he^udA=0,$$
where $dA$ is an area element. The paper is not the only place I find this conclusion, but I cannot trace from what kind of argument would this follow.

But to have this conclusions, means that $\int_M\Delta udA=0$. But why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a compact manifold has empty boundary. You can apply the divergence theorem,
$$ \int_M \operatorname{div}{X}  \, dV_g = \int_{\partial M} \langle X, N \rangle \, dV_{\bar{g}}, $$
where $g$ is the metric, $\bar{g}$ the metric induced on the boundary, and $N$ a unit normal vector field (this is basically the Hodge dual of the general fundamental theorem of exterior calculus, for example). In this case, $\partial M= \emptyset$ and $X=\operatorname{grad} u$, so
$$ \int_M \Delta u \, dV_g = 0. $$

Comment: I didn't see anythin about empty boundary in the question, but maybe it was implicite..

Comment: It's not always specified, but remember that a manifold has to have open sets around every point homeomorphic to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If a manifold is compact, it has to include the boundary, and those points on the boundary only have neighbourhoods homeomorphic to subsets of $H^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:x_n \geqslant 0\}$. Therefore it should explicitly be called a *manifold with boundary* if it has one. Not that everyone agrees on the terminology, but this is how the definitions should fall out.